# Where's PHP time set?

Tags: php, linux

I have a server located in PHX. It is two hours behind where I am, however when I output time:

```
date('H');
```

it shows 5 hours ahead of me. I'm a bit confused.

Comment: The time on the server, not the time where the server is located, is what is used. Also, be aware of time zones.

Comment: I'd bet the server's on UTC.

Comment: Use [`date_default_timezone_get()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php) to find out what's the current timezone (it is set in `php.ini`). Use [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) to use the timezone you want/need.